# Decoding IntelliJ IDEA folder name colors

Tags: git, maven, intellij-idea

I have project, that have 4 Git Roots: `Project`, `Project-commons`, `Project-ui` and `Data Model`.

Due to certain config, I need to put `Project-commons`, `Project-ui` and `Data Model` into `Project` dir. But this resulted in IDEA highlighting `Project-commons`, `Project-ui` and `Data Model` as red folders.

Git still works for me (as well as Maven), I didn't have any merge errors. What does that red highlight mean? Using "Synchronize" option to them helps, until I restart IDEA. I believe it has to do something with 3 Git roots inside another Git folder, but how do I fix it?

It looks like this:

[image]

My IDEA version is 14.1.

Comment: That folder isn't red.  The module may be invalid, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to **Settings → Editor → Colors & Fonts → File Status** and check there what this color means:

[image]

Comment: I found out that my color means "Unknown File Status". Thank you.