# Intellij Out Folder red

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm new to Ij Idea, my Out folder and all files containing in it are red. The code works fine and there is no red weavey line under any file or folder. Any solution to what's causing the issue?

Answer (score -1):

[What do red folders in IntelliJ IDEA mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222154/what-do-red-folders-in-intellij-idea-mean)

Here's described how you can check what each color means. Most likely is because of a special meaning for git, e.g. new unstaged files.

Comment: When you find a duplicate question, then flag the question here as a duplicate with the link to the other question.

Comment: Hi Tom, unfortunately I can only select "spam", "rude or abusive" and "in need of moderator intervention", I don't have "duplicate" and this is why I made an answer. So can you please tell me where to find this?

Comment: You can only find these three because the question is already closed. When you try an open question, then the "duplicate" option is the first entry of the list.